# mongodb php query to return only subobject item

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to duplicate a mongodb query using PHP.

The following query works using the mongo shell.

```
db.user.find({"_id": ObjectId("52d1cedfb1c097b41800055e"), "address.type": "home"},    

{"_id": 0, "address.coordinent.longitude": 1, "address.coordinent.latitude": 1,  "address.zipcode": 1})
```

It returns:

```
{ "address" : [         {       "zipcode" : "84123",    "coordinent" : {
"longitude" : -111.908978,      "latitude" : 40.63147499999999 } } ] }
```

I  do get a result document with the following:

```
$db->user->findOne(array( "_id" => $mongoID))
```

But the following attempts using PHP do not work:

```
$db->user->findOne(array( "_id" => $mongoID), array("address->type" => "home"},{"_id": 0, "address->coordinent->longitude" => 1, "address->coordinent->latitude" => 1,  "address->zipcode" => 1}))
```

And:

```
$db->user->findOne(array( "_id" => $mongoID), array("address[type]" => "home"},{"_id": 0, "address[coordinent][longitude]" => 1, "address[coordinent][latitude]" => 1,  "address[zipcode]" => 1}))
```

What is the proper format for the query in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) in PHP that you have in your `mongo` shell example.

The (untested) query should look something like:

```
<?php
    $query = array(
        "_id" => $mongoID,
        "address.type" => "home",
    );

    $projection = array(
        "_id" => 0,
        "address.coordinent.longitude" => 1,
        "address.coordinent.latitude" => 1,
        "address.zipcode" => 1,
    );

    $db->user->findOne($query, $projection);
?>
```